# Delete a file in linux system after it was read by a process

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I'm looking for a solution to monitor a specific directory and delete all files in that directory once they are read (opened and closed) by a process. I'm not interested in monitoring the particular process, but rather the directory itself. What is the most feasible way to achieve this? I'm ok with developing the solution on my own, just need some initial guidelines/ideas.

Comment: Have you considered inotify?

Comment: find command may be of help here.  For example, "find . -name "*.pdf" -atime -1" will show the file accessed with in a day.

Comment: FWIW, you can delete files while they are still open by a process and yet the process will continue to be able to read them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like inotify. https://superuser.com/questions/181517/how-to-execute-a-command-whenever-a-file-changes have a practical example of what "I think" you are looking for.